# Navigation property (Collection) is only storing one value at a time

Tags: c#, entity-framework

We created a model that has several many-to-many navigation properties that are collections.

```
public class Shop
{
    public Shop()
    {
        Owners = new HashSet<ShopOwner>();
    }

    public ShopOwner Creator { get; set; }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Index("IX_Name", IsUnique = true)]
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessage = "Shop name cannot be empty")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ShopOwner> Owners { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ShopOwner> Partners { get; set; }
}
```

Also,

```
public class ShopOwner : IdentityUser
{
    public ShopOwner()
    {
        Shops = new HashSet<Shop>();
    }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string PreferredName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Shop> Shops { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ShopOwner> manager)
    {
        ClaimsIdentity userIdentity =
            await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

We add owners to shops like this:

```
Shop shop = context.Shops.Find(shopId);
ShopOwner owner = userManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());

shop.Owners.Add(owner);
owner.Shops.Add(shop);

context.SaveChanges();
```

The problem we're having is that adding an owner to a shop's Owners makes that user's owner object the **only** owner in that shop's Owners. It's not acting like a collection, and when we view the database with SQL Server Management Studio, we see a column called `ShopOwner_Id` but no tables or relationships between shops and owners.

Any idea why this collection property could be behaving this way?

Comment: Shop has many owners and owner has many shops ?

Comment: Yes! A shop can have multiple owners and an owner can own multiple shops.

Comment: Sounds like many-to-many , for me...

Comment: Check http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: @sahandnayebaziz Can you also post the code for your `Shop` and `Owner` POCO model?

Comment: @Jenish Rabadiya I've posted the shop and owner models!

Answer (score 0):

I am not much sure about the problem origin here. But still thinks to write how many to many relationship works with EF. So it might happen you get in to the issue and eventually resolve it.

When you define Generic collection in both of POCO model it is considered as Many-Many relationship in EF as in above case in question.

In the backend EF will generate third table for you to store that many to many relationship with the following conventions.

`TableATableB`

So as per this convention you should have a table called ShopShopOwner or ShopOwnerShop (Provided you are not overriding any conventions and table name anywhere.).

Its definition looks like following

```
ShopId ShopOwnerId
  1         2
  1         3
  2         5
```

Below statement would result in one row in above table.

```
shop.Owners.Add(owner);
```

So you are no more required to perform below line.

```
owner.Shops.Add(shop);
```

Second statement may have resulted in violation of primary key in `ShopShopOwner` table. Because the third table introduced by EF will have composite key (ShopId and ShopOwnerId).

Comment: the problem is we aren't getting the any relationship tables in our database. We're only seeing a column in the Shop table called ShopOwner_Id

Comment: @sahandnayebaziz Then how it can be many to many relationship?

Comment: That is the problem! Take a look at the code I posted in the question. Shouldn't this code create a many to many relationship?

Comment: @sahandnayebaziz Is the shop and shop owner in different database?

Comment: they are both in the same database!